# how to disable the scrolling on tableview temporary

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i have side menu in my app. i follow this tutorial for applying it: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift
my problem is: when i swipe the side menu the tableview under i can scroll it and interaction with it. 
i want to disable the scrolling on tableview while the pinGesture is in use (coz by the pinGesture i swipe the side menu)
i try to make view.userenabled = false  while used the side menu but it didn't work, and the view is disable after i swipe for the first time.
so any help please ?

edit:
i was thinking if the scrolling on the tableview done by a gesture ? 
if yes we can use delegate : 
shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer
so we stop all the gesture when the panGesture is active.
any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use the property **scrollEnabled** and set it to **false**.

For Example:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = false;
```

Comment: thank you 
i try this, but also that doesn't happen from the first time of trying slide the menu out.

Comment: is the scrolling on the tableview done by a gesture? 
if yes: i can use the delegate 
shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer
to stop this gesture while the panGesture is active

Comment: Can you add any screen shot to understand it in more detail.

Comment: You cannot control table view scrolling using gesture delegates. Think you are missing a simple logic some where.

Comment: screen shot for what ?

Comment: Screen of table view where you are facing the issue.

Comment: i can't take it sorry :S 
but i'll explain more about the problem:
i have side menu, one of the views under it is a tableview. 
while i swipe side menu, i can scroll the tableview up and down, 
that's what i don't want to happen and try to find a way to know that i'm in tableview and disable the scroll on it.
better now ? 
please any idea can help me. really i give up from this problem!

Comment: I understood that you don't want the user interactions on main view when your side menu is open correct ?
then if it is the case say tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false instead of view.userenabled = false.